# Why is $L^2$ function Hilbert space not defined for Riemann Integral

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

The space of square Lebesgue integrable functions is said to be a Hilbert space. Why is if the integral is Riemann then this is not a Hilbert space? In other words, why not the space of Riemann square integrable functions not a Hilbert space? An example or two would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It would be incomplete. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325710/the-space-of-riemann-integrable-functions-with-l2-inner-product-is-not-comple).

Answer (score 2):

A $L^2$-Riemann Cauchy sequence of $L^2$-Riemann functions can have a nonintegrable limit (see the example of David Mitra).

In general, The Riemann integral behaves much worse that the Lebesge integral. Example: pick a enumeration of rationals in $[0,1]$, $r_1,r_2,\cdots$. The sequence
$$f_n=\chi_{\{r_1,\cdots,r_n\}}$$
of Riemann integrable functions has a nonintegrable pointwise limit.

Comment: Could you please explain how that happens and how that will not happen with Lebesgue integral?

Comment: The limit of your sequence in $L_2$, using Riemann integration, is the zero function.

Comment: True, but my point was about the inadequacy of Riemann integral in general. I will edit.